# jquery datepicker elements not responding to any DOM-modifying js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I'm trying to get date cells in jquery ui datepicker to highlight to the color i want as i click them but the elements dont seem to change at all no matter what i do.

```
<style>
  .mydatepicker-selected {
    background-color: red!important;
  }
</style>
<script>
  var selecteddates = [];

  function highlight() {
    $.each($('td'), function() {
      console.log($(this).html());
      $(this).remove();

    });
  });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(datetext, obj) {
        var dateindex = $.inArray(datetext, selecteddates);
        if (dateindex == -1)
          selecteddates.push(datetext);
        else
          selecteddates.splice(dateindex, 1);
        highlight();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<div id='mydatepicker'></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The td with the text "test" at the bottom of the page is removed but none of the td's in the datepicker are. The console.log shows that i do select all of the td's in the datepicker but the remove function has no effect.  I've also tried less drastic approaches, like add/remove class but none have an effect.  Any ideas? Ultimately i just want to add and remove classes on certain tds to highlight the date cell.

Comment: Just use a delegated event listener

Comment: I've tried using an on click listener and it doesnt trigger. I think the jquery ui catches the event and prevents any other event listeners from triggering. i think the onselect feature was put into it to serve that purpose

Comment: Are you targeting the `<a>` inside each `<td>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want the following styling:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
   background-color: red!important;
 }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that i want to be able to highlight multiple days